# Arrangement of Starting Grid

Tags: forza-motorsport-6

How is this starting grid arranged?

I recently bought the game and don't know about it.I am totally new to racing games. First and second time, I started in the last position but third time, I was suddenly in 12.

How is this arranged?

Answer (score 1):

Often, in real life, the grid is determined with the championship position of the driver in reversal order. Let's say you are rated 12th on 20 drivers and we follow this rule, then you would start at the 8th position. I think this is the case in Forza.